# Python: can't print different JSON response from API

Tags: python, json, loops, response

i wrote simple python script to read letters and numbers in licenseplate in image, to read licenseplate, i'd send it to image recognition API and they will send back JSON response that i use.

this is full code:

```
import glob
import requests
import json
import time
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

def main():
    result = []
    regions = ['id']
    time_to_wait = np.inf
    time_counter = 0

    while True:
        files = glob.glob(os.path.join("./path_to_imagedir/*.jpg"))
        files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
        for file in files:
            if os.path.isfile(file):
                with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
                    response = requests.post(
                        'https://MY_API/',
                        data=dict(regions=regions),
                        files=dict(upload=fp),
                        headers={'Authorization': 'Token ' + 'XXX'})
                    result.append(response.json())
                    resp_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(result, indent=2))
                    if resp_dict[0]['results']:
                        num = resp_dict[0]['results'][0]['plate']
                        print(f"detected number:  {num}")
                    os.remove(file)

        time.sleep(1)
        time_counter += 1
        if time_counter > time_to_wait: break
        print("waiting for file... ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when i run this code, it will show response on terminal like this:

```
waiting for file... 
waiting for file... 
waiting for file... 
detected number:  b1962ub
waiting for file... 
waiting for file... 
waiting for file... 
waiting for file... 
detected number:  b1962ub
waiting for file... 
waiting for file... 
waiting for file... 
waiting for file...
```

i think it's works fine, but the problem is why `detected number` print same number on different image with different number? i don't know what's wrong is it.

any helps will be appriciated!
thankyou

Comment: You need to clear `results=[]` within your loop, not outside, otherwise you are appending new results to the list, but only displaying the first, at `[0]`

Comment: how to clear `results=[ ]` ?

Comment: Yes, put `results=[]` inside your `for file in files` block.

Comment: yea, it's same result like https://stackoverflow.com/a/62509874/8361239 answer, it doesn't work with multiple image in file. how to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to separate multiple images in a single JPEG file?  I don't know that much about graphic file formats to know if they naturally support multiple images internally, or you have to cut them apart digitally with image processing software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you keep appending to your `results` but you always look at `resp_dict[0]` so you always look at the same item. instead look at `resp_dict[-1]` so you will look at the NEWEST item

so this:

```
if resp_dict[0]['results']:
                        num = resp_dict[0]['results'][0]['plate']
                        print(f"detected number:  {num}")
```

should be this:

```
if resp_dict[-1]['results']:
                        num = resp_dict[-1]['results'][0]['plate']
                        print(f"detected number:  {num}")
```

Comment: ah i see, it works with only one image input, but does't works with many inputs

Comment: it not that it doesnt work, it just that you read the response of the first one you tried instead of the last one you tried

Comment: how to make it works with multiple inputs? @Nullman

Comment: how do you mean? multiple inputs where?

Comment: i'm sorry, i mean how to make it works with many images in folder? @Nullman

Comment: if the directories are near eachother you can change your glob to something like "./path_to_imagedir*/*.jpg". if they are not then remmember that glob returns a list, you can just combime multiple globs. `files = glob.glob(path1);files.extend(glob.glob(path2))`

Comment: i got this error when i put two or more image inside folder. but it's working well when i put image one by one.
```py
waiting for file... 
waiting for file... 
waiting for file... 
waiting for file... 
detected number:  b1962do
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image_sender.py", line 93, in <module>
    main()
  File "image_sender.py", line 47, in main
    if resp_dict[-1]['results'][0]:
KeyError: 'results'
```

Comment: that means that your API call didnt return something with a "Result" field. you should add a try/except block to catch it when it happens and see what went wrong

Comment: i don't know why even though this is can read and send many images, API just response one JSON object constantly